# What is best Test Automation tool/approach for automating GTK GUIs on windows

Tags: python, gtk, automated-tests, ui-automation, gtk3

I want to automate the GUI testing of our application.
(windows app with GTK GUI running on Linux back-end).
Problem is conventional tools are not useful for automating GTKs.

This application's GUI is developed in GTK and I launch that app on windows OS.
Application is developed in C++ mostly. It is connected to Linux server back-end.

As of now I am using AutoIt which but  but it is not 100% reliable I want better solution.
I am thinking about using  'dogtail (Python)' but do not know how to use it for 
windows apps with GTK GUI running on Linux back-end.

Any tool/Programming language solution for this problem will be appreciated.

I use QTP for windows apps and selenium for web apps mostly,
but both of them are useless for GTKs(Correct me if I am wrong).

Comment: Running on windows may be a problem -- I'm not sure if the GTK+ accessibility stuff works there and that's really a requirement for any automated UI testing. Something like  https://gitlab.com/dogtail/dogtail could work for you though: it allows scripting and/or recording UI actions.

Comment: @jku I am aware of using  gitlab.com/dogtail/dogtail  for GTK+ on Linux, Not sure how to use it with windows.

Comment: Seems like either there is no solution for GTKs apart from autoIt approach or nobody has ever tried it.

Comment: 3 years later there is still none. And dogtail seems to be unmaintained and wont be useable with gtk4 that will be released in a few month. GUI testing seems to be not worth enough for most people.